# How to alter tableview cell text?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I want to alter some of the static cells after I do other processing.  I have outlets set up for the cells that I want to modify, but when I look at them using NSLog, they show nil, which indicates to me that I don't have the correct cell.  For instance, in the image below I want to add the start time to the label just like I did for Date (date was done when creating the cells for which I got the current date),

[image]

I tap on the disclosure indicator which takes me to another scene (this was created in Storyboard, using segues to get from one scene to another) where I get the two times I need.  I then return to the main scene (shown) and try to alter the Start Time label, but nothing happens.  A NSLog of the label prior to trying to alter it returns this:

> oStartTimeCell.textLabel.text: (null)

I have read in one of the Apple docs that this textfield is read-only.  If that is true in this case, is there a way I can reload the cells with the updated information?  Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: With static cells, you set up outlets between your controller and the labels in the cells, not the cells themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong approach. You should not create a reference to a cell using an outlet. Once the cell moves out of the visible view, the outlet will either be null or contain garbage data. Even if (in your situation) the cell will never move out of view, I think it shows you're trying to use a UITableView in a way that was not meant to be.

Instead put the data you want to display in your cells in a dataSource, e.g. an array.

The tableView should use the dataSource to configure the values displayed in the textLabels of the cells. Once you want to update the text displayed in the cells, change the values in the dataSource and call `reloadData` on the tableView to force the tableView to call `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and related UITableViewDataSource methods.

Comment: I think you're on to something here... right now, the table uses static cells; I'll have to change them to dynamic..let me code it up and I'll get back to you, probably tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an IBOutlet for each cell and connect it:

```
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell1;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell2;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell3;
```

And also change your method to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(indexPath.row == 0) return cell1;
    if(indexPath.row == 1) return cell2;
    if(indexPath.row == 2) return cell3;

    if (cell == nil) {
        //create cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: -cellForRrowAtIndexPath only gets called when the cells are initially created; once I go back, it never gets called again.  Outlets were already created and filled with the data I got from the date/time routines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UILabel to display the text ? . If you are just create an outlet to the `UIlabel` and update it any method like `cellForRwoAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` etc that is called after you tableView is loaded.

If you are not using a UILabel and just using cell.textLabel you could do something like 
`cell.textLabel.text = @"ChangedText"` in `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod`. Make sure you are editing the required cell by checking `indexPath.row`

Do `[tableView reloadData]` to call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: -cellForRowAtIndexPath never gets called after the initial building of the cells... (see comment below)